# Why gdb command "info locals" also print undeclared variable?

Tags: gcc, gdb

```
int a = 10;
if(a >= 5)
    printf("Hello World");
int b;
b = 3;
```

For example I command "info locals" before execute line 4 "int b;" but gdb print information of variables a and b. Why gdb work like this and how can I print only declared variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the way the compiler decided to compile your code.
In your case, I believe that since variable `b` will always be used in your code, then the compiler might "declared" both `a` and `b` together to optimize execution time.

If you really want to understand what happened, disassemble the program and see the assembly that actually runs when you execute this code.
I assume you will discover that the instruction that allocates the space on the stack frame for the variable `b` allocated the space for both variables (`a` & `b`) at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

gdb shows b variable because it has been declared by your compiler

Assuming this code is inside a function, once execution flow enters the function it allocates local variables in the stack, this is where a and b values reside. That's because the compiler reads your code and makes all declarations at the beginning, even if they haven't been declared on top of your function.

Take a look at [How the local variable stored in stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50524734/how-the-local-variable-stored-in-stack)